# Partial View Asynchronous Loading , Not loading , No Errors

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, partial-views

Vs'12 C# Asp.net MVC4, Internet Application Template + Kendo UI.

**Description**

I'm coming from an `KendoUI_DropDownList`. This fires an event that places the value of the selected item from the DDL into My `Ajax Script`. This Script is passes the value "1" to my `Contoller`. This controller starts my `Partial View` and is supposed to return it to my `<div id="LoadingPartialDataDiv"></div>`.

**Code**

- My Div that i want the `_PartialView` to be placed in

  ```
  <div id="LoadingPartialDataDiv"></div>
  ```
- Kendo DDL

  ```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("OptionsDrop")
        .BindTo(new string[] { "Leasehold", "Owner", "Stranger" })
        .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
      )
  ```
- Script

  ```
  function change() {
      var val = $("#OptionsDrop").val();

      $.ajax({
             url: '/ImageView/Leasehold/',
             dataType: 'Post',
             data: { id : val },
             success: function (data) {
                    $('#LoadingPartialDataDiv').html(data);
             }
      });
  });
  ```
- Controller

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  public PartialViewResult LeaseholdA(string id)
  {
      int xx = Convert.ToInt16(id);
      var trct = db.Tracts.Find(xx);
      return PartialView("_Leasehold", trct);
  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  @model OG.ModelData.dbTract  

  Something Really Simple to test

  ViewBag.Title = @Model.TractNumber;
  ```

**Question**

I receive absolutely no errors, I can even debug ( stepping through the code ) and see that it runs everything, without error. My values are being passed from Script to Controller and From controller to the _partialView. Yet my _partialView does not appear.... Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably is not this but did you notice:

```
var val = $("#OptionsDrop").val();
data: { id : var }` **`<-- should be "val"
```

another thing I don't know much about those **KendoUI controls** but maybe you need to adds some scripts into your page.

Edit: try to add some code inside your partial view to check if Render is happening.

Comment: yeah sorry that is a type of mine. In the code I'm actually passing it as an integer 1.

Comment: On the kendo and script side, all the code runs, as stated above. Its just simply not showing the _partialView

Comment: your ajaxcall is dataType: 'Post'